# VPN Connection Trust this app dialog

Tags: android, vpn

[image: VPN]

I was using DNSSet app and when I opened it it showed me this dialog.

My question is  what this dialog is and when accepted what it will do and how can we create one like this on our own ?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out myself. Actually this is a Android System dialog message which is called when you try to prepare a VPN connection.
Following code will make this popup visible.

```
Intent vi = VpnService.prepare(MainActivity.this);
            if (vi != null) {
                startActivityForResult(vi, 3);
            }
```

Note that startActivityForResult is important as it will cause this popup to appear.
I was missing this line therfore it was not coming